# VB.NET - Unable to click data within datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview in a form and it opens within a panel. When it opens you can't click any of the cells in table. You can click the cells when the form opens not in the panel. I'm guessing that it's something to do with the way the form opens within the panel, But i'm not sure.

I'm able to reorder the table and resize rows.

```
People.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
People.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
People.Visible = True
Panel2.Controls.Add(People)
```

[Image of table within panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ierbo.png)

Comment: Don't do this; just add the datagridview to the panel, rather than adding a whole form that contains a datagridview, to the panel. You'll end up with funky behaviour if the form-inside-the-panel intercepts events instead of passing them on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot or will not extract your datagridview from your people form (and throw the peopleform away), add this to the People form:

```
Public Readonly Property TheGrid As DataGridView
  Get
    Return Me.DataGridViewNameHere
  End Get
End Property
```

Then add the grid to the panel, not the whole form:

```
Panel2.Controls.Add(People.TheGrid)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think i will open the people form in a new window and not within a panel. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: If the aim was to make something like an MDI application, you can [make an MDI application..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications)